# How to use array values in where clause of select query?

Tags: php

i know this is a duplicate one..

but i couldn't find what i wanted ..

I have an array value like this

```
$startpoint= (implode(",",$_SESSION['strtpnt1']));
// "chennai,madurai,tirunelveli,Kanyakumari"
```

I'm using a select query in a select box to fetch the datas from database which are not in array

My query looks like this:

```
$sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN='" . implode(",",$_SESSION['strtpnt1']) ."'";//i tried this and 

$sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN='" . $startpoint ."'";//this
```

Comment: first mistake "remove = sign after IN "

Comment: You don't want to build a SQL query like this. Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: @jack ,i removed the = sign and tested the query in mysql loaclhost wampserver the query works fine...but when i implemented it in my code ..i couldnt get the values in the select box....

Comment: @ram Another problem, another question.

Comment: No @Jack d same one why is not working in my php code...

Comment: It may stem from the same thing you're working on, but as far as we're concerned, it's a different question.

Comment: k fine any way thnks for ur time in it.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'`s as they are `string`s -

```
$startpoint= implode("','", $_SESSION['strtpnt1']); // Escape values if needed
```

And the query will be -

```
$sql21 = "select start from tbl_place where start NOT IN ('" . $startpoint ."')";
```

No `=` needed.

Comment: The reason for downvote?

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted your solution (looks good at the first sight), but he should escape the string before using $_SESSION vars in a SQL query. E.g., using MySQL:

`$escaped = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_SESSION['strtpnt1']);`
`$startpoint= implode("','",$escaped);`

Comment: @André thats right if the values are taken from user.

Comment: @André your comment makes no sense who says he's using `mysql_*` ?

Comment: @Daan that's like a precaution.

Comment: Judging from the level of OP's expertise I would deem the risk quite high that `$_SESSION['strtpnt1'] = $_POST['strtpnt1'];` can be found elsewhere in the code.

Comment: But could any1 guess the reason of downvote?

Comment: @Daan: You are right, maybe he is not using mysql_*, so a different escape function may be the right one. I updated my comment with an "e.g." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for using IN in mySQL is:

```
SELECT something FROM something WHERE something NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

So don't use the =.